# AVplayer not playing live audio stream

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer, avplayeritem

I have a custom UI for the AVplayer with all the bells and whistles like a scrubber to seek a button to play/pause the audio in a separate view controller. I have them on a two tab bar controllers, one of streaming audio and the next for live streams, when a playable stream is selected, the view controller shows up and if the stream selected is not a live stream, the audio plays but if it is a live stream, the stream doesn't start until the user hits the play button. Underneath it is the same player instance for both the stream, all that is changing is the URL to play.

I know this is not descriptive enough as I cannot share the code.Any help will be appreciated

Comment: I've had issues like this in the past but I can't remember them too clearly now. I remember having to play around with the different KVO updates to find where the stream wanted to start and then I had to manually tell it to start playing. Look into `AVPlayerItemStatus.readyToPlay`.